# Guest operating system ubuntu-mate 22.04.3 jammy jellyfish display does not autoresize when run on fedora workstation 38 using virt-manager

Tags: display, ubuntu-mate, virt-manager

I am running ubuntu-mate jammy-jellyfish 22.04.03 as a guest operating system on fedora-38-workstation using virt-manager. The display does not autoresize when I resize the virt-viewer window. Can you please review and assist ?

Please note guest os Ubuntu 23.04 lunar lobster does autoresize

Please review and assist!

Comment: Good day, have you looked [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990600/virt-manager-guest-resize-not-working) before asking the question in this forum? It is certainly a Virt-Manager and not a guest problem

Comment: I have explored all possibilities but I am not able to figure out why it is happening. Please help

Comment: Do your other guests behave accordingly? Or is none of your guests resizing? Please state in your question (by editing it) which possibilities you have tried, so we do not have to guess.

Comment: Hi Mr. kanehekalli I am edited my issue description. Please review and assist